# Creating arrays from Command line in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, command-line

Just had a very simple question. I want to create an array based on command line arguments. I know the general structure is something like this.

```
int *foo = NULL;

void make_me(int argc, char *argv[]){

}
```

I tried doing this

```
  int *foo = NULL;

  void make_me(int argc, char *argv[]){
     int bar = 0;
     for(bar; bar < argv.length; bar++){
         foo[bar] = argv[bar];
     }
}
```

But no luck so far

Comment: You need to allocate some memory.

Comment: What do you mean by _no luck so far_? Please [edit] your question to add what happened vs what you expected. Did it not compile? Were there compiler errors to add? Did it compile, but not run as you expected?

Comment: `argv.length` ==> `argc` but asking for luck is like "hit and hope" - do some research.

Comment: Would that look something like foo = malloc(sizeof(*foo) * argc); ?

Comment: `int *foo` is the wrong type.

Comment: But I'm trying to create an array of integers

Comment: ... and `argv[bar]` is type `char*` not `int`.

Comment: So do I need to type cast?

Comment: maybe `foo[bar] = atoi(argv[bar]);`

Comment: If the program is called with `program_name 123 456 789`, what should be the result?  How about with `program_name 123 qwe 789`?

Comment: *"So do I need to type cast?"* - **no**. you need to understand the real problem you're having, then attack it by refinement. You *appear* to want to convert command line arguments to `int` values that you can use in your program. The keyword there is *convert*. Casting in C rarely has its uses, and is pretty-much *never* the right thing to do when beginning to learn the language. If you have a warning/error that you conceal with a cast, chances are very high your logic is wrong. So, *no*, don't cast; *fix*.

Comment: Guessing syntax will not get you very far in C programming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you haven't specified how your program will be called, I'll assume that you can call it passing numbers or other strings that aren't necessarily numbers as arguments.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){ //argc = number of arguments, argv = array with the arguments
    int i, j, number, value, arraySize = 0;
    int *myArray; 
    char ch;
    for(i = 0; i<argc; i++){
        number = sscanf(argv[i], "%d%c", &value, &ch); //read formatted data from string in order to identify if it's a number or not
        if (number == 1) { //if it's a number
            arraySize++;   //increment by one the size of my array
        }
    }
    //So far, I know how many numbers there are in my argv.
    if(arraySize > 0){ //if there are any numbers on argv
        myArray = malloc(sizeof(int)*arraySize); //dynamically allocate my array in order to store all numbers from argv without "wasting" space.
        for(i = 0, j = 0; i<argc; i++){ //notice that now I'll use two different indexes: 'i' and 'j'. 'i' is to iterate over argv, and 'j' is to index numbers on myArray
            number = sscanf(argv[i], "%d%c", &value, &ch); //read formatted data from string in order to identify if it's a number or not
            if (number == 1) { //if it's a number 
                myArray[j] = value; //copy it to 'myArray'
                j++; //increment 'j' to store the next valid value
            }
        }
        for(i = 0; i<arraySize; i++){
            printf("%d ", myArray[i]); //just so you can see your final result
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

E.G:

`./my_program 1 woz 2 other 3 string 4`, assuming you named the program `my_program`

Output:

`1 2 3 4`.

Comment: I have no idea why that got downvoted, I tried to upvote but I'm a new user so it won't show.